# How to prevent mouseover function to execute while the mouse moves within the DOM element - Backbone Events

Tags: javascript, html, events, backbone.js, tooltip

I am using Backbone's delegate events to bind a mouseover method to **many `DIV`s with class `job-op-wrapper`**
which looks like this -

```
<div class="job-op-wrapper" data-info="CLEN1">
    <div class="job-op"></div>
    <span class="job-op-code">CLEN1</span>
</div>
```

This is how i have attached the event handler

```
events: {
            "mouseover .job-op-wrapper": "showTooltip",
            "mouseout .job-op-wrapper": "hideTooltip"
        }
```

this is the event handler whose job is to show the custom tooltip

```
        showTooltip: function (event) {

            // Get the content to be displayed inside the tooltip
            var info = $(event.currentTarget).data('info');
            var html = ['<div class="title">'+info.OpCode+'</div>'];
            html.push('<div class="desc">Description</div>');

            // Display the tooltip
            $('.tooltip').html(html.join(''));
            $('.tooltip').css("opacity", "1");
            $('.tooltip').css("left", ((event.pageX -15) + "px"));
            $('.tooltip').css("top", ((event.pageY - 130) + "px"));
        },

        hideTooltip: function () {
            $('.tooltip').css("opacity", "0");
        }
```

Now, the problem is, that when the mouse moves WITHIN this DIV, `showTooltip` method gets executed. As a result, tooltip appears to flickers (which is because I am calculating and changing tooltip's position in the event handler).

What I want is that it should appear once the mouse enters the DIV and does not change its position while the mouse stays within the DIV. How can I achieve that?

I tried  binding the event handler to following events instead of mouseover for the DIV but, still the tooltip flickers:

```
hover
focus
mouseenter
```

I also tried to attach another event handler on `mousemove` and called `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault().` But, it did not work.

Any suggestions ideas?

Comment: Have you tried giving a fix height instead of `(event.pageX -15) + "px")` ?

Comment: The height cannot stay fixed because there are many DIV s that needs a tooltip. So, every time mouse hover over any of those DIVs, the tooltip needs to be repositioned on top of the respective DIV

Comment: You say that you tried using `mouseenter`, did you compliment it with `mouseleave` or did you keep using `mouseout`? As @tom lankhorst's answer suggests using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` should get you the behavior you are looking for. If you were still using `mouseout` mousing over child elements could be what is causing the flicker, `mouseleave` should fix that.

Comment: I tried that but no difference

Answer (score 1):

You should replace *mouseover* with *mouseenter* and *mouseout* with *mouseleave*. These jQuery events will stop the mouseover and mouseout events be called when you enter a child element.

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/

Comment: Yes Tom, I tried that as well but no luck. :( The tooltip still flickers

Comment: Hey Tom, I also tried to strip out all the child nodes from the tooltip so that it looks like this --> '<div class="tooltip">this is a tooltip </div>' . but, still no luck

Comment: That is really weird. Could you try to log the mouseover and mouseenter events (console.log)? Is the log also flickering in the same way as the element?

Comment: I tired that, and yes the event handlers are being called as the mouse moves